# ASP.NET Core Health check - UI fails on authentication

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, health-monitoring

I'm trying to implement the ASP.NET Core 2.2 health check feature. Setting up the health check itself isn't the problem, but I also want to be able to use the UI feature. Right now I get the exception message

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <.

after some debugging I found that the GetHealthReport call from within the HealthChecks.UI package gets redirected to the login page. Calling the same uri from the browser works fine. 
I guess it may be related to the fact that the actual login occurs in another application (regular ASP.NET MVC). 
Is there perhaps a way to set allow anonymous access or something else to fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by moving UseHealthChecks up inside the Configure method, so it comes before adding the authentication middleware.